# textures that are bigger than 4096 x 4096?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Using iPad 2 simulator , after i have created a sprite sheet, its size was ±8000 pixels, i got warning that `is bigger than the supported 4096 x 4096` .

The Animation is made of images in the size of half iPad screen, and each animation has 10 frames .

So , how can i create a sprite sheet to run the animation ? do i need 2 sprite sheets? and if yes , is there a way to run them in sequence ?

```
   [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:plist];
    hotGirl= [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:pngFirst];
    hotGirl.position=ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/1.335);
    [self addChild:hotGirl];

    NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i < num+1; i++)
    {
        CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i.png",file,i]];
        [animFrames addObject:frame];
    }
    CCAnimation* Animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animFrames delay:0.1f];
    CCAnimate * pAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:Animation];
    id call=[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(done:)];
    id seq=[CCSequence actions:pAction,call, nil];
    [hotGirl runAction:seq];
```

Thanks .

Comment: you need to split the atlas into two, each no larger than 4096x4096

Comment: Are you sure you need full screen sprites? That's fairly intense and you only get so much texture memory. You might want to make sure you are breaking your animation logical parts.

Answer (score 0):

Its openGLES Texture memory limitation.

```
int maxTexSize;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &maxTexSize);
printf("Max = %d\n",maxTexSize);
```

You can't load image that is larger than GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE. It depends on device.